# <img> not appearing on iPad.

Tags: ios, html, image, css

I'm experimenting with different techniques using Amazium here http://stevengeorgeharris.com/croft/croft; when viewing on an iPad the image of the ballet dancer is missing, yet appears on everything else including Nexus 7 and iPhone 5. I have played around with positioning and z-index's but nothing happens.

I then went into IOS simulator to use web inspector and I noticed when I refresh the page the image appears and quickly disappears again. I cannot for the life of me find the cause of the problem, maybe I am over looking something very simple, as I usually do.

Comment: FYI, you include libraries that depend on jQuery before you include jQuery on your page.

Comment: I haven't done my post-completion scan of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` for it to show up on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

i just see the website try to add overflow:hidden it will be good in regular explorer but it will not work in iOS but look nice